# How do I grant permisions to user(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, permissions, sql-grant

Using the query, not the GUI. I created a user for AdventureWork2014 with the default_schema person. How do I give him permissions to use the "sale" schema as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what permissions you want to give the user on the sale schema, you could use this query:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: sale TO user ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT permission  [ ,...n ] ON SCHEMA :: schema_name  
TO database_principal [ ,...n ]  
[ WITH GRANT OPTION ]  
[ AS granting_principal ]
```

**Arguments**

- *permission*
  Specifies a permission that can be granted on a schema. For a list of the permissions, see the Remarks section later in this topic..
- *ON SCHEMA :: schema_name*
  Specifies the schema on which the permission is being granted. The scope qualifier :: is required.
- *database_principal*
  Specifies the principal to which the permission is being granted. One of the following:

  - database user
  - database role
  - application role
  - database user mapped to a Windows login
  - database user mapped to a Windows group
  - database user mapped to a certificate
  - database user mapped to an asymmetric key
  - database user not mapped to a server principal.
- *GRANT OPTION*
  Indicates that the principal will also be given the ability to grant the specified permission to other principals.
- *AS granting_principal*
  Specifies a principal from which the principal executing this query derives its right to grant the permission. One of the following:

  - database user
  - database role
  - application role
  - database user mapped to a Windows login
  - database user mapped to a Windows group
  - database user mapped to a certificate
  - database user mapped to an asymmetric key
  - database user not mapped to a server principal.

For further reading, please refer to the entry on Microsoft Docs, [GRANT Schema Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql).